# Java busca el método main donde no debe buscarlo. Error: no se ha encontrado el método principal en la clase

Tags: java

Tengo 4 clases y 1 interfaz en el mismo paquete. Serie, Genero Cinematografico, Pelicula, Ejecutable (contiene MAIN) y la interfaz IVisualizable.

Al ejecutar "ejecutable" (desde terminal), se ejecuta correctamente e imprime y trae todo correcto. Al ejecutar desde la terminal cualquier otra clase me sale el siguiente error que antes no salía.

> ```
> ➜  src javac com/company/GeneroCinematografico.java ➜  src Java
> com.company.GeneroCinematografico Error: no se ha encontrado el método
> principal en la clase com.company.GeneroCinematografico, defina el
> método principal del siguiente modo:\n   public static void
> main(String[] args)\nde lo contrario, se deberá ampliar una clase de
> aplicación JavaFX javafx.application.Application.
> ```

Probé heredarle el "Application" pero al correrlo se abre una ventana java y se traba todo. Antes esto no sucedía.

Código de la clase Genero Cinematografico:

```
package com.company;

import com.company.IVisualizable;

public class GeneroCinematografico implements IVisualizable {
    public String titulo;
    protected String genero;
    protected String creador;
    protected int duracion;
    // protected boolean visto = false;
    protected boolean visto;

    public GeneroCinematografico( String titulo,String creador){
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.creador = creador;
    }
    public GeneroCinematografico( String titulo,String creador,String genero, int duracion){
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.creador = creador;
        this.duracion = duracion;
        this.genero = genero;
    }

    public GeneroCinematografico() {
        this.titulo = "undefined";
        this.genero="undefined";
        this.creador="undefined";
        this.duracion=0;
        this.visto=false;

    }

    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }

    public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }

    public String getGenero() {
        return genero;
    }

    public void setGenero(String genero) {
        this.genero = genero;
    }

    public String getCreador() {
        return creador;
    }

    public void setCreador(String creador) {
        this.creador = creador;
    }

    public int getDuracion() {
        return duracion;
    }

    public void setDuracion(int duracion) {
        this.duracion = duracion;
    }


    protected String aImprimir;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        aImprimir = "titulo='" + titulo+
                ", generso='" + genero
                +
                ", creador='" + creador +
                ", duracion=" + duracion  +
                ", visto=" + visto  ;

        return aImprimir;


    }

    @Override
    public void marcarVisto() {
        this.visto = true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean esVisto() {
        return visto;
    }

    @Override
    public double tiempoVisto() {
        return duracion;
    }
}
```

Comment: Es que ***debes*** lanzar la clase que tiene el `main()`, no cualquier clase del paquete... Si la clase que intentas ejecutar no tiene método `main`, la JVM no sabe qué hacer con ella

Comment: El método `main` es el punto de inicio de toda aplicación Java, si un a clase no posee un este método no puede se ejecutada como punto de partida de un programa.

Answer (score 0):

Debes crear una clase que sirva de punto de inicio de tu aplicación. Puede llamarse `Aplication` ,por ejemplo, y en esa clase agregar el método `main()`

Esto sería:

```java
public class Application {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Aquí va el código que se ejecuta al inicio de tu aplicación. Ej: Instanciar tu clase "GeneroCinematografico" y hacer algo con ella

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Toda aplicacion en java requiere de un Metodo "main" del cual todo se desprende, si no hay uno, le es imposible al JVM compilar y generar los $class.
Crea una nueva clase (.java) en la cual incluyas el metodo main, este tiene esta estructura: [tipo de acceso] [ajuste en memoria] [retorno] [nombre] (parametros){ }

```
public static void main (String[] args){  
 //aqui mandas llamar todos los metodos que existan en tu programa 
}
```

Llamas los metodos por un objeto de las otras clases

```
Clase objNomnre = new Clase();
```

Y los llamas

```
objNombre.Metodo();
```